# Bootstrap - make the images inside the column with the same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, grid-layout

How can I make the images inside the column all having the same height?

I am trying to make a grid layout like this [site](http://www.spystudio.co.uk/).

This is my attempt with [bootsrap](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oBQXPp).

But I can't make the heights the same:

[image]

Code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Is it something I need to do it on the image side? If so, what sizes of images that I should comply to?

Or is it something I should to it on javascript side or CSS?

Or a plugin that I should use?

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried the `.row-eq-height` class from bootstrap ? http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/ which is using flexbox

Comment: @MihaiT that is making the columns have the same heights. i m looking for making the images having the same heights.

Comment: also, that `.row-eq-height` causes a bug when you are on smaller screen. it forces the 3 columns stay the same even you use `col-md-4` for large and medium screen and want these 3 columns become 1 columns on small screens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i made you an example of how you can achieve what you want.

is by using `background-images` instead of images. so first you make the columns equal as height, and then use background-images same as the imgs you put in the `.grid-items` . and you hide the first img with `opacity:0` ;

you need to keep the original imgs so that the `grid-items` have a physical height

Let me know if this works for you

see > **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/29535/)**

code used in CSS

```
.grid-item {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 5px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height:100%;
}
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}


.row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display:         flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin:10px 0;
}
.row > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.row > [class*='col-'] > [class*='col-'] {
  height:100%;
}
a.grid-item img { opacity:0}
a.grid-item { background-size:cover }

.col-md-3 .col-md-12 + .col-md-12 {
  margin-top:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x1200')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x1200')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"> <a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x600')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x600" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12"><a href="#" class="grid-item" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/800x1200')"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/800x1200" alt=""> </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i don't understand why you have this in css `a.grid-item { background:url("http://placehold.it/800x600") no-repeat scroll center top / cover }
.col-md-3 .col-md-12 + .col-md-12 {
  margin-top:10px;
}`

Comment: so what happens to the image of 800x1200 and others of 800x600 on the html?

Comment: as i explained. the original imgs must be left in html because if you delete them or use `display:none` on them, the `.grid-items` won't have any `height` . with the help of them, you set a height you want on your rows ( and columns ) . but you hide them with `opacity:0` and add different background-images to each column . in my example i added only one img as background. but you will need to add to each col a background-image. this is the only way i could think that you can make all columns equal in height and the imgs to fill the whole column

Comment: edited my answer with a new JSFIDDLE + html so you can see what's going on. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: inline css image background is the only solution. thank you!

Comment: glad i could help. Cheers :D